# How can I try this jquery plugin - Galleria?

Tags: jquery-plugins

Ok. I have some experience with HTML and CSS, little with Javascript and none with JQuery.
And I'm trying to try out in my HTML file the Galleria plugin with fullscreen theme but I can't make it work. ( http://galleria.aino.se/ )

It only show the empty page with no pictures. I took the source code from the demo page and I pasted in my page and after some little modifications with the url of the theme, I managed to have on my screen only the image, without the "mechanism". Any help?

I think the instructions were made for an old release of the plugin and that's the reason I can't get it work.

P.S. I found a ready made demo on googlecode, but I can't get the fullscreen feature. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing debug:true to yield more errors if you are seeing a blank page. Regarding customizations, try the documentation and API reference.